# `make` error : Nothing to be done for `all'

Tags: terminal, makefile, libtool

I'm trying to compile IRSTLM toolbox on my mac. I successfully run `regenerate-makefiles.sh` and `./configure` but I get this error when executing `make` :

```
1 warning generated.
mv -f .deps/verify-caching.Tpo .deps/verify-caching.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -isystem/usr/include -W -Wall     -ffor-scope -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES  -DMYCODESIZE=3 -g -O2   -o     verify-caching verify-caching.o -lirstlm  -lz
libtool: link: g++ -isystem/usr/include -W -Wall -ffor-scope -    D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -DMYCODESIZE=3 -g -O2 -o .libs/verify-caching     verify-caching.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  /Users/alinejad/Downloads/irstlm-    5.80.08/trunk/src/.libs/libirstlm.dylib -lz
Making all in scripts
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
```

I've already checked tab in 'all' command.

Comment: There is no error here. make simply tells you that there is nothing to do because everything has already been done.